# Deleting a row from gridview bound manually?

Tags: asp.net, sql, vb.net, gridview

I have a gridview which is bound to a table that allows to download files. The table consists of:

- tableid as int
- filename as string
- filepath as string
- delete (added column in the gridview)

This deletion is not automatic, it is coded. I want the user to click on delete and the row selected will be deleted. Simple as that, but I cant seem to get the ID of the row to be deleted. This is what I have done:

```
  Try
        'Get the Image_Id from the DataKeyNames
        Dim imgId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value)


        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("delete from FilesTable where id=@id", con)
        cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@id", imgId)
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.Text
        con.Open()
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery()
    Catch ex As Exception
        ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(Me, Me.[GetType](), "Message", "alert('Error occured : " & ex.Message.ToString() & "');", True)
    End Try
```

But I keep getting error that string output cannot be converted to Integer:

> Error Occurred: Input string was not in a correct format.

Please Help!

This is how the grid view is bound:

```
Private Sub BindGridviewData() 
    Try 
        con.Open() 
        Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from FilesTable", con) 
        Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd) 
        Dim ds As New DataSet() 
        da.Fill(ds) 
        con.Close() 
        gvDetails.DataSource = ds 
        gvDetails.DataBind() 

    Catch ex As Exception 
        Response.Write(ex.Message) 
    End Try 
End Sub
```

Comment: Have you tried debugging and seeing what the value of `gvDetails.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value` is? I expect it is not something that can be converted to an integer. How are you binding your grid view?

Comment: Private Sub BindGridviewData()
        Try
            con.Open()
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("select * from FilesTable", con)
            Dim da As New SqlDataAdapter(cmd)
            Dim ds As New DataSet()
            da.Fill(ds)
            con.Close()
            gvDetails.DataSource = ds
            gvDetails.DataBind()
        Catch ex As Exception
            Response.Write(ex.Message)
        End Try
    End Sub

Comment: Yes I did and the value is  = 0 which it shouldnt be

Comment: Does the table `FilesTable` have a primary key? I can't test at the moment but I suspect DataKeys is not automatically set unless the table that is being bound to it has a primary key? You may need to set the [DataKeyName Property](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.ui.webcontrols.gridview.datakeynames%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) before calling `Databind()`

Comment: Yes it Does its called id as you can see in the code above!!

Comment: I cannot see anywhere in the code above where it says ID is a primary key, you can have a column called ID that is not a primary key, you can have an identity column that is not a primary key. Simpply stating that your column is called ID is not an indicator that your table has a primary key. On a separate note, 0 will convert to an integer just fine, are you sure this is what `gvDetails.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value` evaluates to at runtime?

Answer (score 0):

I found the answer after a long time and it was a simple problem:

Instead of:
Dim imgId As Integer = Convert.ToInt32(gvDetails.DataKeys(e.RowIndex).Value)

I changed it into:

Dim imgId As Integer = Int32.Parse(gvDetails.Rows(e.RowIndex).Cells(0).Text)